# Java - Screen Change Transitions

Tags: java, graphics, transition

I have been working on a game and the code is some what solid. I have about 7 classes and it runs with no bugs but the graphics don't run smoothly. At the beginning of the game there is a start menu like almost every other game. The menu looks great but when I press the button the screen blinks white before the level comes on. I am using pure java with a simple Jframe and GamePanel. I also use very basic double buffering. The level image loads in a different class the the GamePanel one which contains the start screen image. I have looked into moving the level image into the GamePanel and nothing changed. Feel free to ask me any questions to go more in depth.
Thanks,
Dev

Comment: Maybe a simple example demonstrating your problem would be of more value?  The only things I can think of is something is preventing the paint process from getting the results to the screen or the there is nothing for it to paint by default...

Comment: Try to post a http://sscce.org/